# oj-module pass parameter between router states

Tags: oracle-jet

created a navbar template project and trying to pass parameters between states

```js
self.moduleConfig = ko.observable({'view': [], 'viewModel': null});
self.modelParams = ko.observable({});
self.loadModule = function () {
 ko.computed(function () {
  var name = self.router.moduleConfig.name();
  var viewPath = 'views/' + name + '.html';
  var modelPath = 'viewModels/' + name;
  var masterPromise = Promise.all([
   moduleUtils.createView({'viewPath': viewPath}),
   moduleUtils.createViewModel({'viewModelPath': modelPath})
  ]);
  masterPromise.then(
    function (values) {
     var viewModel = null;
     if (values[2])
      viewModel = values[1];
     else
      viewModel = new values[1](self.modelParams);
//                                    self.moduleConfig({'view': values[0], 'viewModel': values[1]});
     self.moduleConfig({'view': values[0], 'viewModel': viewModel});
    }
  );
 });
};
```

I am trying to pass state parameters getting below error:-
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: values[1] is not a constructor

Answer (score 0):

I have used this block of code

```
self.loadStepModule = function () {
                    ko.computed(function () {
                        self.slotBody({'view': [], 'viewModel': null});
                        var myview = modviewPath + currentStep.viewName + '.html';
                        var mymodel = modmodelPath + currentStep.modelName;

                        var masterPromise = Promise.all([
                            moduleUtils.createView({'viewPath': myview}),
                            moduleUtils.createViewModel({'viewModelPath': mymodel})
                        ]);

                        masterPromise.then(
                                function (values) {
                                    var vm = new values[1](currentStep.dataparams);
                                    self.slotBtns(self.currentButtonConfig());
                                    self.slotBody({
                                        'view': values[0],
                                        'viewModel': vm
                                    });
                                }
                        );
                    });
                };
```